# JUNG change the color of specific vertex

Tags: java, graph, jung

at the moment, I'm trying to change the color of a specific vertex in JUNG.
I know i can use the following function to change the color of all nodes.
Is it possible to substitute v from the following line with a specific node.

```
vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintFunction(v -> Color.blue);
```

Or should i use  transformer classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly supply a more complex `Function` than `v -> Color.blue` if you like; for instance:

```
vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintFunction(
    v -> v.equals(specialNode) ? Color.red : Color.blue);
```

For more information on specifying `Functions` (using lambda expressions or not), see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html.